# What does .* operator do in C++?

Tags: c++, visual-c++, operators

What does a.*b operator do in c++? i have found this reference:
"Object pointed to by member b of object a", but it doesn't work in the following example:

```
class Color {
    public:
    int red,green,blue;

    Color():red(255), green(255), blue(255){}
    Color(int red, int green, int blue) :red(red), green(green), blue(blue){}

    void printColor(){
        cout << "Red:" << red << "  Green:" << green << "  Blue:" << blue << endl;

    }
};

class Chair{

    public:
    Color* color;

    private:
    int legs;
    float height;

    public:
    Chair(int legs, float height):legs(legs), height(height){
        color = new Color(255, 0 , 0);
    }

    void printChair(){
        cout << "Legs: " << getLegs() << " , height: " << getHeight() << endl;
    }

    int getLegs() { return legs; }
    float getHeight(){ return height; }

    Chair& operator+(Chair& close_chair){
        this->legs += close_chair.getLegs();
        this->height += close_chair.getHeight();
        return *this;
    }

};

int main(){
     Chair my_chair(4, 1.32f);
     my_chair.*color.printColor();
     return 0;
}
```

When i use my_chair.*color.printColor(); in main, i get 'color' : undeclared identifier. I run this example in Visual Studio.

Thank you.

Comment: `.* (member access through pointer to member), `

Comment: The part that needs to be shown is not ...

Comment: Have you pasted the wrong bit of code?

Comment: `.*` is dereferencing a *pointer-to-member*, not a member that is a pointer. Where did you find that "reference"?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`.*` is to dereference a pointer-to-member, but you are just wanting to dereference a member pointer. To do this, use `->`:

```
my_chair.color->printColor();
(*(my_chair.color)).printColor(); //same thing
```

Using `.*` in your example would look something like:

```
auto colorP = &Chair::color;
(my_chair.*colorP)->printColor();
```

Answer (score 4):

If you want to dereference the `color` member, do this:

```
my_chair.color->printColor();
```

or

```
(*my_chair.color).printColor();
```

The operator `.*` dereferences a pointer-to-member.

A pointer-to-member - a "member pointer" - is different from a member that is a pointer.
It does not point "into" a specific instance of a class, so you need an instance that the "pointer" can be related to.

Example:

```
struct A
{
    int x;
    int y;
};

int main()
{
    A a{1, 78};

    // Get a pointer to the x member of an A
    int A::* int_member = &A::x;
    // Prints a.x
    std::cout << a.*int_member << std::endl;

    // Point to the y member instead
    int_member = &A::y;
    // Prints a.y
    std::cout << a.*int_member << std::endl;    
}
```